# Rails many to many model with select in the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

The logic in the exercise is create a Bill where a Bill have a list of Products with an amount of them.

I have the next 3 models:

- Bill
- Product
- BillItem (This is the intermediate model between Bill and Product for the many to many relationship)

Schema for more clarity:

```
create_table "bill_items", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "amount"
  t.integer  "product_id"
  t.integer  "bill_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.index ["bill_id"], name: "index_bill_items_on_bill_id"
  t.index ["product_id"], name: "index_bill_items_on_product_id"
end

create_table "bills", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "user_name"
  t.string   "dni"
  t.date     "expiration"
  t.float    "sub_total"
  t.float    "grand_total"
  t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
end

create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.string   "description"
  t.float    "price"
  t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
end
```

First i have a list of created products in my database.
For my BillController i have a _form.html.erb where i want be capable to create dynamic selects for choose a product and set a amount.

My view is the next:

```
<%= form_for bill do |f| %>
  <div>
    <%= f.label :user_name %>
    <%= f.text_field :user_name %>
  </div>

  <div>
    <%= f.label :dni %>
    <%= f.text_field :dni %>
  </div>

  <div>
    <%= f.label :product %>
    <%= f.collection_select :product_ids, Product.all, :id, :name %>
  </div>
  # Here i should add more selects if the user want to add more products.

  <div><%= f.submit %></div>
<% end %>
```

My problem or my question is: how to "groupe" the ids of the products and the amount of them. And the another question is, i can create the other selects dynamically with JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be adding multiple `BillItem` to your form to account for the amount and the product. This is done through [accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) on the model. For example:

```
class Bill < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bill_items
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :bill_items
end
```

Initialize a `BillItem` on the `Bill` in your controller:

```
class BillsController < ActionController::Base
  def new
    @bill = Bill.new
    @bill.bill_items.build
  end
end
```

Then in your form, use the [fields_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for) helper to create sub-forms:

```
<%= form_for @bill do |f| %>
  <div>
    <%= f.label :user_name %>
    <%= f.text_field :user_name %>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= f.label :dni %>
    <%= f.text_field :dni %>
  </div>

  <%= f.fields_for :bill_items do |f| %>
    <div>
      <%= f.label :product %>
      <%= f.collection_select :product_id, Product.all, :id, :name %>
    </div>
    <div>
      <%= f.label :amount %>
      <%= f.number_field :amount %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit %></div>
<% end %>
```

And yes, you can [use javascript to create new nested forms](https://github.com/ncri/nested_form_fields).

Comment: Thank you for take the time to help me, your answer is what i needed :)